# (Playwright async ) How to fix :' AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'inner_text' '

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright

I have written a async playwright function but I don't know how to put this assignement into my function , using `await`.
Here is the line of code that cause me error :

```
country = await feedback.query_selector('[class="user-country"]').inner_text()
```

This is what I get in my console as error :

```
    country = await feedback.query_selector('[class="user-country"]').inner_text()
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'inner_text'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ElementHandle.query_selector' was never awaited
```

I would appreciate any help from you.
Thank  you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be: `await (await feedback.query_selector('[class="user-country"]')).inner_text()`. But we discourage from using ElementHandles, see here: https://playwright.dev/docs/next/locators#locator-vs-elementhandle